# I have 3 nav icons, when one is hovered over it should display a solid circle behind it

Tags: css, navigation, hover

The nav links/icons: http://d.pr/i/tawN

When I hover over them it should look like this: http://d.pr/i/VKI7

Ultimately, I'd like the current page's icon to be a different color as well (class="current")

I tried doing this with border-radius but it wasn't smooth. Does it require JS?

Thanks!

Comment: Which browser did you use that didn't display your border-radius solution smoothly? This one works for me in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/LGt9H/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using border radius should produce quite a smooth circle in all browsers that support the border-radius property: http://jsfiddle.net/Mveqj/

```
div {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: #000;
}
```

To have your icon a different color when it has a class of active you'll want to swap out the current icon for another icon which is the correct color.

I'd recommend using a sprite for this so you're just adjusting the background position on your image when the 'active' class is enabled.

More info on spirites here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: maybe use pseudo :after in your css